# Regex fail to match everything if one char don't match

Tags: regex, date

I'm building regex for date time format, it should allow to write day as d or dd, month as M or MM and year as yyyy and also the time with H or HH or h or hh, minutes and seconds and even am or PM with t or tt. So this is the regex I've built and works partly except for a minor thing:

```
(\b(d{1,2}|[-\/ :;]|M{1,2}|y{4}|h{1,2}|H{1,2}|m{1,2}|s{1,2}|t{1,2})\b){5,13}
```

this allows me to write something like "yyyy-M-dd" or "MM-yyyy-d H:mmtt" and other variants of that.
The problem is if I write "yyyy-M-ddx" it will match the "yyyy-M-dd", and not match the "x" and I need that if something doesn't match then everything else don't match. Is there a way in Regex for that? Basically I need something that cancels the match in case something doesn't match.

Is it possible?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Do you want to match patterns like `yyyy-M-dd` and `MM-yyyy-d H:mmtt` ? Your current pattern uses an alternation matching an alternative from what is listed and repeat that 5-13 times. This can also match for example `MM MM M` If you want only the specific variants, then you would have to use an alternation specifying exactly what should be allowed to match.

Answer (score 0):

Add start of input `^` and end of input `$` anchors to each end of your regex:

```
^(\b(d{1,2}|[-\/ :;]|M{1,2}|y{4}|h{1,2}|H{1,2}|m{1,2}|s{1,2}|t{1,2})\b){5,13}$
```